# How to use jquery with an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find child of a specific element with jquery. But i couldn't figure out how to use jquery functions on an element that is already selected. For example i already select a div and i want to reach it's child span.

I tried `selectedElement.$('span')` but it didn't work as expected;

```
selectedElement = e.target;
console.log(selectedElement.$('span'));
```

It says $() is not a function. How would i use jquery after selecting an item like this?

Comment: try `$(selectedElement).find('span')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write it in jQuery I would do it like this:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('span'));
});
```

When you click a div the output will show you the element span in that div.